# Aorus FO48U monitor makes constant loud popping/ticking noise

Tags: audio, display, troubleshooting, speakers, repair

I've started to experience a serious problem with my Aorus FO48U monitor all of a sudden. The speakers are malfunctioning: they play sound in a very muffled, distorted and quiet way. Furthermore, there's now a constant ticking noise (that seems to be coming from the right speaker) whenever any video input is connected (even if I'm not playing any sound). I've tried plugging and unplugging the input sources, as well as resetting the monitor settings and turning off the monitor (and unplugging it), but this very annoying noise never stops.

If nothing is connected, and the “no input” banner is showing, then the noise is absent but appears as soon as any source is connected to display video (even if the source is not currently playing audio). Unfortunately I can’t seem to find any way to completely disable the built-in speakers on the monitor.

It happens on both my computer via a DisplayPort cable and an Apple TV via HDMI, so I find it very strange that both cables would be faulty at the same time.

What should I do / what's causing this? Does it have to be replaced? Thank you in advance.

Example of the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_iCtU8yUyGxA_nfqNjpwxvWKMuD8FouA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: More likely, the monitor is faulty. How old is it?

Comment: @harrymc less than a month old

Comment: Use the warranty and have it replaced or reimbursed.

Comment: @harrymc I'm going to but I'd rather try other options first if possible, since I would have to spend weeks without a replacement.

Comment: Try the monitor with another computer, to see if the problem persists. If it persists, then the problem is with the monitor, but any trafficking with the monitor will void the warranty. If the problem disappears, check that your display driver is the latest on the *manufacturer's website*. Also update BIOS and Windows.

Comment: I'm also having an issue with ticking noise from the speakers. It is some sort of electrical interference. The noise doesn't happen if I lean close to the monitor, mostly when sitting in my chair. Unplugging devices near it didn't seem to help, but turning off my office lights (recessed LED lights) seems to make it go away. I know that seems strange, but with electrical interference those things can happen. What's annoying is that I can't shut down the speaker, because I'm not using it anyway. It appears susceptible to interference.

Comment: @Alan that’s interesting but I couldn’t find a possible source of interference. Just for curiosity, were the lights causing interference all along or did that problem arise just after a while? Because there’s nothing different in my environment that I could think of

Comment: @AndreaPerugini I'm not sure it's the lights. Mine makes noise when I switch windows between dark and light colored windows (sometimes). I found out that if I put my hand next to the screen or lean forward the ticking stops. Also if I take the white colored window and drag it around I can kinda 'clear it' the screen it makes noise then stops for a while. The noise seems to come from the lower left near the speaker but could be some sort of electrical component it's hard to tell. Sounds like a cricket/bug or ticking.

Comment: @AndreaPerugini I recorded some audio of the clicking and with some quick analysis it appears to be 10 hz ticking noise. I uploaded a wav file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PV7znLVpwBBz1Ijp3Y6myBaE6E8TEVNK/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @AndreaPerugini I figured out my problem, it's not the monitor! Sorry for the confusion. A while back I found my old Citizen watch and I had it sitting on my desk. Apparently any time I switched to a white screen my watch would emit the ticking noise. It's a citizen Ecodrive that uses solar cells. I moved my watch today and the sound came from a different direction. That's why my lights and monitor affected the noise, it was because the watch is light sensitive.